# Use Android Number Keypad but allow negative numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext, android-inputtype

I have an `EditText` field that I would like to only enter negative or positive numbers.

When I use `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER` it will bring up the nice numeric keyboard which is what I want; however it will only let you enter positive numbers even though the negative button is on the numeric keyboard.

I tried using the `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED` and it will allow the user to enter negative or positive numbers like I want; however it brings up the standard alphabetic keyboard.

Is there anyway to bring up the numeric keyboard and allow negative numbers?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

```
android:inputType ="numbersigned"
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

for your EditText in XML, you can force the input type to number only by using android:inputType XML attribute set to numberSigned, number or numberDecimal. You can also force it via [setRawInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType(int)).

You can also force the keypad to show only numbers by [setting android:digits XML attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `android:inputType="number|numberSigned"` or in Java `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)`

Answer (score 0):

```
fromEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
                    | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Now this allows you to set Negative/Decimal/Standard numbers